# Cucumber setup issue in intelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, cucumber

**Environment**: Windows10, Java8, IntelliJ, Cucumber

I have followed a article and tried to setup Cucumber in IntelliJ and run the feature files, however, it doesn't help

```
http://www.edgewords.com/2018/05/31/intellij-with-cucumber-and-selenium-webdriver-java/
```

I just wanted to keep it simple for the start and setup a skeleton cucumber feature and run it, but I have an error like this:

```
Error running 'Scenario: add to basket': com.intellij.execution.testframework.sm.SMTestRunnerConnectionUtil.createAndAttachConsole(Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/intellij/execution/process/ProcessHandler;Lcom/intellij/execution/testframework/TestConsoleProperties;Lcom/intellij/execution/runners/ExecutionEnvironment;)Lcom/intellij/execution/testframework/ui/BaseTestsOutputConsoleView;
```

**Screenshot**:
[image]

**POM.xml file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>MyCukes</groupId>
<artifactId>MyCukes</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.11.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.1</version>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.21.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>MyRunner.java</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.21.0</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
```

**This is my Settings.xml file for Maven, I am not sure if there's anything got to do with this or not? *

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<localRepository>${user.home}/.m2/repository</localRepository>
<interactiveMode>true</interactiveMode>
<usePluginRegistry>false</usePluginRegistry>
<offline>false</offline>
```

Comment: the scenario in the error is different from what you have in the screenshot. are you sure you are running (pointing to) the correct files?

Comment: Codes should be added as code blocks and not as images. That makes it searchable and readability increases too.

Answer (score 0):

My bad!!!  I thought Gherkin was installed, showever not. Problem fixed.